# Getting the Network Credentials of a running process?

Tags: windows, networking, security, kerberos, credentials

If a Windows program is run with ‘runas’ using the  ‘/netonly’ argument is there any way to see what credentials are being used by it for the network?  Similar to the way you might see a process is being run by a certain user in the task manager, or in ‘tasklist’ or in Get-Process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following as any user with administrative privileges. Naturally, this only works **after** the process -- that has been started with `runas /netonly` -- accessed a network resource.

- Open a command line with elevated permissions (*Run as Administrator*) and enter `klist sessions`.
- Search for the session where it says `Negotiate:NewCredentials` (comes from the `/netonly` switch ➜ logon type 9) and that contains the username that executed the `runas` command.
- Note the session id, e.g. *0x154f7a8*.
- Enter the command `klist -li 0x154f7a8`. This will show you all the kerberos tickets for this session. The kerberos tickets are granted to the user account that was used for the `runas /netonly` command. If the command does not return any tickets, then the process has not yet accessed a network resource, thus did not receive a ticket yet. In that case I think your only chance is to use something like *mimikatz* to read the cached credentials from memory.

Comment: Interesting info - would not work if only NTLM authentication is used though.

Comment: @Daniel This is great, but it doesn't tell me which process id is associated with the ticket...(or is it just ...the last ticket listed from `klist -li <session-hex-id>`?)

Comment: @Daniel So the processes go to the system that go to Keberos that retrieve the tgt that sends the system the ticket?